# What is the difference between per-process-limit and highwater in iOS OOM reason？

Tags: ios

The system jettisoned the process for many reasons. But what is the difference between per-process-limit and highwater ？

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/identifying_high-memory_use_with_jetsam_event_reports

Comment: I have read this article, but I still don't quite understand the difference between the two, especially high water. I think per-process-limit means that every app has an upper limit on memory usage, but high water hardly understands what it means.

Comment: "High water" generally refers to peak memory usage during memory intensive tasks, but that doc suggests it’s only applicable for daemons. But I'm not sure if it really matters. Are you really seeming both `per-process-limit` and `highwater`? And the prescription for both is the same, namely reduce the peak ram usage as outlined in that doc.